# Alpha Characters to 32-bit integer

Tags: binary, 32-bit

I was going through the PluralSight tutorial on hashtables/string hashing and came across an example of hashing called "folding" in which the presenter proceeded to, in groups of four, convert string characters to 32-bit integers.

In the first 4 characters, the letters "lore" he states "And when you take the bytes of those characters and then just cram them together into a 32-bit value, we end up with a 1.7 billion value", and he presents the number, "1701998444".

How did he come up with "1701998444" from the letters "lore"?

[image: theimage]

Comment: `x[0] << 24 + x[1] << 16 + x[2] << 8 + x[4]`. That is, each byte (8 bits, representing a character in ASCII) in the 4-byte group is "shifted" into position in a 32-bit integer (which is made up of .. 4 bytes).

Comment: Very cool...thanks so much!

Comment: That said, I did the math and am getting 1819240549 :} - `(108<<24)+(111<<16)+(114<<4)+101`. So it's encoded *reversed* as e-r-o-l (e<<24..) as opposed to l-o-r-e (l<<24..) -- and I've no good explanation for why one would want to logically reverse the characters.

Answer (score 2):

Every English letter has an ASCII number code assigned to it.
'A' is 65. 'Z' is 65 + 25 = 90.

Each base 10 integer corresponds to a binary integer, as shown below.

```
l -> 108 -> 1101100
o -> 111 -> 1101111
r -> 114 -> 1110010
e -> 101 -> 1100101
```

Then in reverse order:

```
"erol" = 1100101011100100110111101101100 = 1701998444
```

The reason the string is stored in reverse order is due it being stored as   "little endian", compared to "big endian".

This article explains it nicely: [Little Endian](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/embed/chap3/chap3.htm)